# Error starting weblogic server

Tags: weblogic

Starting Weblogic Server is not starting the server and the console is forced to shutdown. I couldn't figure out why this is happening. Any help is really appreciated.

I tried running the admin console and here is the error message:

```
    Access is denied.
    .
    .
    JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
    .
    WLS Start Mode=Production
    .
    CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;C
    :\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\o
    racle_common\modules\oracle.dms_11.1.1\dms.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_commo
    n\modules\oracle.jmx_11.1.1\jmxframework.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\
    modules\oracle.jmx_11.1.1\jmxspi.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\
    oracle.odl_11.1.1\ojdl.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\common\wlst\lib\adf-share-m
    beans-wlst.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\common\wlst\lib\mdswlst.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\common\wlst\resources\oamap_help.jar;C:\O
    racle\Middleware\as_1\common\wlst\resources\oamAuthnProvider.jar;C:\Oracle\Middl
    eware\as_1\common\wlst\resources\ossoiap_help.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\comm
    on\wlst\resources\ossoiap.jar;C:\
    Oracle\MIDDLE~2\ORACLE~1\soa\modules\commons-cli-1.1.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\ORAC
    LE~1\soa\modules\oracle.soa.mgmt_11.1.1\soa-infra-mgmt.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\OR
    ACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\WLSERV~1.3\server\li
    b\xqrl.jar
    .
    PATH=C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sys
    tem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
    1.6.0_43;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\opmn\bi
    n;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\opmn\lib;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\perl\bin
    .
    ***************************************************
    *  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
    *  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
    *  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
    *  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
    ***************************************************
    starting weblogic with Java version:
    java version "1.6.0_43"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
    Starting WLS with line:
    C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_4\bin\java    -Xms256m -Xmx512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
     -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\WLSERV~1.
    3\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true   -da -Dplat
    form.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\WLSERV~1.3
    \server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\WLSERV~1.3\server   -Xms512m -Xmx1024
    m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Doracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1
     -Ddomain.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\FormsReports -Dcommon.
    components.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.co
    mmons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\O
    racle\MIDDLE~2\USER_P~1\domains\FORMSR~1 -Djrockit.optfile=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\OR
    ACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.server.config.dir=
    C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\USER_P~1\domains\FORMSR~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\AdminServer
     -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\USER_P~1\domains\FORMSR~1\config\
    FMWCON~1  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\USER_P~1\domains\FORMSR~
    1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\USER_P~1\doma
    ins\FORMSR~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Orac
    le\MIDDLE~2\USER_P~1\domains\FORMSR~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.d
    eployed.app.dir=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\USER_P~1\domains\FORMSR~1\servers\AdminServer
    \tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:
    \Oracle\MIDDLE~2\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~2\ORACL
    E~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.ne
    t.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false  -Dwc.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Midd
    leware\as_1 -Dclassic.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1  -Dem.oracle.home=C:
    \Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dweblogic.management.
    discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsT
    oConsole=false  weblogic.Server
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:50 AM SGT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ J
    CE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this
    check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:50 AM SGT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the defaul
    t Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable
    this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:50 AM SGT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebL
    ogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 20.14-b01 from Sun Mi
    crosystems Inc.>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:51 AM SGT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic
     Server 10.3.6.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050 >
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:52 AM SGT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server stat
    e changed to STARTING>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:52 AM SGT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing sel
    f-tuning thread pool>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:52 AM SGT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server
    log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\FormsReports\servers\AdminSe
    rver\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written
    to this file.>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:53 AM SGT> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000438> <Unable to load perfo
    rmance pack. Using Java I/O instead. Please ensure that wlntio.dll is in: 'C:\PR
    OGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_4\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windo
    ws;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Syste
    m32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.
    6.0_43;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\opmn\bin;
    C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\opmn\lib;C:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\perl\bin;C:\Program
     Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;.'
    >
    Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ssp.CsfWalletManag
    er openWallet
    WARNING: Opening of wallet based credential store failed. Reason java.io.IOExcep
    tion: C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\FormsReports\config\fmwconfig\b
    ootstrap\cwallet.sso (Access is denied)
    Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.file.FileKeyStoreIn
    tegrityChecker <init>
    WARNING: Key store file integrity checker initialization failed. Reason oracle.s
    ecurity.jps.service.keystore.KeyStoreServiceException: JPS-01050: Opening of wal
    let based credential store failed. Reason java.io.IOException: C:\Oracle\Middlew
    are\user_projects\domains\FormsReports\config\fmwconfig\bootstrap\cwallet.sso (A
    ccess is denied)
    Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.file.FileKeyStoreMa
    nager openKeyStore
    WARNING: Opening of file based keystore failed.
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM SGT> <Error> <Security> <BEA-090892> <The loading of OPS
    S java security policy provider failed due to exception, see the exception stack
     trace or the server log file for root cause. If still see no obvious cause, ena
    ble the debug flag -Djava.security.debug=jpspolicy to get more information. Erro
    r message: JPS-06514: Opening of file based keystore failed.>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM SGT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server su
    bsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: The l
    oading of OPSS java security policy provider failed due to exception, see the ex
    ception stack trace or the server log file for root cause. If still see no obvio
    us cause, enable the debug flag -Djava.security.debug=jpspolicy to get more info
    rmation. Error message: JPS-06514: Opening of file based keystore failed.
    weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: The loading of OPSS java secu
    rity policy provider failed due to exception, see the exception stack trace or t
    he server log file for root cause. If still see no obvious cause, enable the deb
    ug flag -Djava.security.debug=jpspolicy to get more information. Error message:
    JPS-06514: Opening of file based keystore failed.
            at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.lo
    adOPSSPolicy(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1402)
            at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.in
    itialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1022)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityS
    erviceManager.java:873)
            at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
            at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsRuntimeException: JPS-06514: Opening of file b
    ased keystore failed.
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.<
    init>(PolicyDelegationController.java:167)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider.<init>(Ja
    vaPolicyProvider.java:369)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
    orAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
    onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsException: JPS-06514: Opening of file based ke
    ystore failed.
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getDefaultPDPServ
    ice(PolicyUtil.java:2855)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getPDPService(Pol
    icyUtil.java:3097)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.<
    init>(PolicyDelegationController.java:164)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider.<init>(Ja
    vaPolicyProvider.java:369)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: oracle.security.jps.service.keystore.KeyStoreServiceException: JPS-06
    514: Opening of file based keystore failed.
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.file.FileKeyStoreManager.openKe
    yStore(FileKeyStoreManager.java:374)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.file.FileKeyStoreServiceImpl.do
    Init(FileKeyStoreServiceImpl.java:104)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.file.FileKeyStoreServiceImpl.<i
    nit>(FileKeyStoreServiceImpl.java:76)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.file.FileKeyStoreServiceImpl.<i
    nit>(FileKeyStoreServiceImpl.java:66)
            at oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.KeyStoreProvider.getInstance(Ke
    yStoreProvider.java:157)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    >
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM SGT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server stat
    e changed to FAILED>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM SGT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical s
    ervice failed. The server will shut itself down>
    <Oct 7, 2015 9:30:56 AM SGT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server stat
    e changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>

    C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\FormsReports>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason WebLogic Server is unable to access cwallet.sso. It looks like there's a couple of other files along the way it can't access as well.

Check permissions on the domain directory structure and make sure your current user can access required files. If that doesn't help at all, try running startWebLogic as an Administrator user on the machine.

Comment: I tried running startWebLogic as Administrator but the console is forced to shut down.I couldn't even see the error message.

Comment: What do the permissions look like on the directory structure for the domain, and particularly the cwallet.sso file?

Also, it would be worth opening Task Manager to check for any rogue WebLogic Server java processes that might still be running.

Lastly, how was the domain created? Was the current user you're trying to run the admin server under used to create it?

Comment: You were totally right!!Awesome!Thanks a bunch..Something went wrong with the permission.I made some changes and I can start the server now.Thanks again.You are my lifesaver..Have been struggling with this since last week and I was told I gotta install everything back.You saved my time..fuhh

Comment: Pleasure! I've been caught by that too many times myself. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just recently had a problem with an incorrect set of JCE Unlimited Jurisdiction files. Moving them back to the old version made this error go away.

Comment: Got that problem too, switched to the original ones and it started fine. Now  I need to find the proper version.